# IUIAutomation.ElementFromPoint does not give precise value for browser controls

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I wrote a C# program to find the information about controls at a point. To do this, I call ElementFromPoint method of IUIAutomation. It gives IUIAutomationElement. From that I get properties of the element, such, as CurrentControlType, CurrentName, CurrentBoundingRectangle.

This works well in applications like MS Word, Notepad. But when I try to find information of an element in a browser, it only identifies the document, which is the client area of the browser. So, even if I try to get information about a button in the client area, it only identifies that it is the client area. It does not identify the button.
I tested in IE, Chrome and Firefox. In all these browsers, I am facing this problem.
Please let me know how to get precise information about the control at a point inside a browser.

If not UI automation, is there any way I can write a C# program to get the information about the control under mouse cursor in a browser the way "Inspect" of Chrome finds? Please note that the browser will not be running inside my application.